# Help with an exercise from Kunen's book

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

I've been having a hard time deciphering Kunen's suggestion in the following exercise:

[image]

Overall, I'd like to get a little more direction in solving this exercise. Specifically, I would like some help determining precisely who the poset $\mathbb{P}$ is. From what is said there, it seems to me that the set $\mathbb{P}$ is the product $[2^{<\omega}]^{<\omega} \times [E]^{ <\omega}$, but, if this is correct, I haven't been able to find the adequate partial order that makes everything work well.

On the other hand I imagine that, once it is revealed who $\mathbb{P}$ is, it will be more or less easy to say which are the dense subsets that one needs to apply $\mathsf{MA}(|E|)$; however, if it's not too much trouble, a little guidance on this matter would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would define the poset that is described is as follows:

A condition $p \in \mathbb{P}$ is a triple $(t,n,e)$, where $n \in \omega$, $t$ is a function from $2^{\leq n}$ to non-empty rational open boxes of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ such that $s \subseteq s' \in 2^{\leq n}$ implies $t(s') \subseteq t(s)$ (the hint also says that incompatible $s$ should map to disjoint boxes, but this will be irrelevant by a density argument) and $e$ is a finite subset of $E$. Whenever $(x,y) \in e$ it gives you a promise that the Cantor set defined by the generic tree contains $(x,y)$. Thus we should additionally require that for every $(x,y) \in e$ there is some $s \in 2^n$ such that $$(x,y) \in t(s).$$

Now the order is the "natural" extension relation: $$(t',n',e') \leq (t,n,e) $$ iff $t \subseteq t'$, $n \leq n'$ and $e \subseteq e'$.

Can you make it from here?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I will do my best, but, if you allow me, I would like to ask you a few questions: $1.$ By $2^{\leq n}$ do you mean the set $\{s: m \to 2 | m\in \omega \ \wedge \ m\leq n\}$?; $2.$ Do you think the construction will work if we change the rational boxes to non-empty open sets only?; and $3.$ With the $\mathbb{P}$ you propose, is the natural step also to take $\mathbb{Q}$ as the finite support product of $\omega$ copies of $\mathbb{P}$ or do you have another way in mind?

Comment: Also, I think Kunen had in mind that the collection $\{I_s \times J_s : s\in 2^{<\omega}\}$ determines a Cantor scheme with certain properties so that, in turn, a Cantor set appears at the end. However, I have the impression that there should also be a feature in $\mathbb{P}$ that ensures that the diameters of the $I_s \times J_s$ converge to $0$. What do you think?

Comment: @Peluso 1. Yes, 2. No, otherwise $\mathbb{P}$ is not $\sigma$-centered, 3. Yes. To your other question, that the diameters of the boxes converge to $0$, follows by defining appropriate dense sets and using genericity.